# Custom message box with character counter not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this custom code to set the count to the number of characters, but instead, it is setting the count to literally this ${textLength}

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const count = document.querySelector('.count');

function countLetters() {
  const text = textarea.value;
  const textLength = textarea.value.length;
  count.innerText = '${textLength}';
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox">
  <h3>Message</h3>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" onkeyup="countLetters()"></textarea>
  <p>Total Characters : <span class="count">0</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Template literals use backticks `count.innerText = \`${textLength}\`;`  or just `count.innerText = textLength;`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo.
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have the value in textLength variable. Just use it directly.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const count = document.querySelector('.count');

function countLetters() {
  const text = textarea.value;
  const textLength = textarea.value.length;
  count.innerText = textLength;
}
```

```html
<div class="MessageBox">
  <h3>Message</h3>
  <textarea placeholder="Message" onkeyup="countLetters()"></textarea>
  <p>Total Characters : <span class="count">0</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo type questions should be closed and deleted. A question that results in changing `'` to `\`` is a ***typo-type*** question in my opinion

Comment: Thank You I'm still new I didn't know it was possible